# MySQL SELECT statement with COLLATE and MATCH

Tags: mysql, select, match, match-against, collate

Is there any way to specify `COLLATE` and `MATCH() AGAINST()` in the same query string. I'm trying to get this.

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE COLLATE latin1_general_cs MATCH(column) AGAINST('string')
```

I know that won't work, just an example.
If `COLLATE` dose not work with `MATCH`. How can I specify the case sensitivity in every query, because I need both case sensitive and case insensitive `MATCH() AGAINST()` queries.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.
Like @Ollie Jones said, I copied all data it to a new column,with case sensitive collation. In my case `latin1_general_cs`.

But because `FULLTEXT` indexes can NOT have mixed collation. There must be 2 `FULLTEXT` indexes. One on the case insensitive column (`latin1_general_ci`)and one on the case sensitive column (`latin1_general_cs`).

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately

> Although the use of multiple character sets within a single table is
>   supported, all columns in a FULLTEXT index must use the same character
>   set and collation.

There's no modifier on the full text `MATCH() AGAINST` syntax to specify collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

You could maintain a copy of the `column` column with a different collation.